# Angular force form validation on load with Material form controls

Tags: angular

I need the form validation to show up when the form loads. The problem is the only way I've been able to get it to show up for a `mat-radio-group` is to call `form.markAllAsTouched()`. But on the initial load (a user coming back to the form) there isn't a hook I can find to latch onto where I can call that method. I've tried `ngAfterViewChecked()`, but it throwing errors.

Comment: Can you share the errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to do the following immediately after create the form:

```
this.sampleForm = this.formBuilder...

setTimeout(()=>{
   this.sampleForm.patchValue(this.myForm.value)
})
```

Comment: Using setTimeout to call markAllAsTouched worked. I called it in the subscribe of the Observable which pulls the data for the component on load. Can you explain how this works?

Comment: Because setTimeout puts the inside function in the end of the javascript queue so while javascript process is running it will pop up from the stack and call the operation. anything in the queue will get called only if the stack is empty. so setTimeout tells javascript to hold the this code till you finish your work. Remember to Check my answer as correct if it works. Thanks a lot